# Use MR GitLab predefined variables after successful MR

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I have a simple *.gitlab-ci.yml*:

```
stages:
  - test
  - build

.docker_image: &docker_image
  image:
    name: foo
    entrypoint: [""]
  tags:
    - deploy

test:
  stage: test
  <<: *docker_image
  script:
    - 'echo $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID'
    - 'echo $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME'
  only:
    - merge_requests

build:
  stage: build
  <<: *docker_image
  script:
    - export
  only:
    - stage
```

How can I use `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID` and `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME` in a build job?

I need this to add information to the commit message.

Comment: `$MERGE_REQUEST_IID` and `$MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME` are only available in Merge-Request Pipelines, see the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#predefined-variables-for-merge-request-pipelines). So I think the answer to your question would be that this is not possible (by design).

Comment: @SuicideS3ason that’s right. I found other solution)